# What is the simplest way of testing that a React Component contains a html node with enzyme?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

When unit testing react components I often check for the existence of a child node based on the presence or content of a prop.

With enzyme, I find the element using `.find` on either the shallow or mount wrapper and then check if the length of that is 1. With chai, this would look like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MYReactComponent/>);
const innerNode = wrapper.find('some-css-selector');
expect(innerNode.length).to.equal(1);
```

Is there a better way of checking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you're testing for existence via selector as in your example and need to use a method that returns `ShallowWrapper`, then yes you need to use `.length`. But you don't necessarily need separate statements for it:

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<MYReactComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find('some-css-selector').length).to.equal(1);
```

For that matter you could consolidate the whole thing in a case like this if you want:

```js
expect(
  shallow(<MYReactComponent />)
  .find('some-css-selector').length
).to.equal(1);
```

If you're testing based on component type / props then you may be able to use `contains()`, which returns boolean:

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<MYReactComponent />);
expect(wrapper.contains(
  <div class="something">
    <span>content</span>
  </div>
)).to.be.true;
```

Comment: Thanks @JMM, I think .contains might be a solution for some of the use cases. Still, for most of the time I'm still going to be forced to use `.length` or I'll have to recreate the inner child that I want to check.

Comment: @JMM what if you want to check for atleast 1 child and not exactly 1?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`exists()`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/exists.md):

`expect(wrapper.find(MyComponent).exists()).toEqual(true)`

Answer (score 1):

Can skip find by directly using `exists`

```
expect(wrapper.exists('some-css-selector')).to.equal(true)
```

Also works with other React Components nicely

```
import SomeOtherReactElement from 'path/to/SomeOtherReactElement';

...
...

expect(wrapper.exists(SomeOtherReactElement)).to.equal(true)
```